How to remove Windows from a dual boot system?
After trying dual boot, I want to remove the Windows partition and keep Ubuntu. How can I do that? I am concerned if I remove the Windows partition then I might not be able to boot Ubuntu anymore. I also want to make sure my files on Ubuntu will be fine.

In Ubuntu, open the app gparted. You may have to install it first. Once open, select the drive from the top right menu. Take a screenshot of the gparted window. Edit your question and add the screenshot in your question. This will help us understand the partitions structure of the drive, and which ones to delete.

Have a Windows backup. We find users who remove Windows and later find they have one program or game that they really want, but only runs in Windows. Convert all NTFS partitions to Linux format, like ext4. You must backup & restore as reformatting will erase data. You cannot repair NTFS from Linux and it will need repair, chkdsk, or defrag which only can be done from Windows. Or at least create a Windows repair/recovery flash drive with repair tools.

To the close voters: The OP wants to remove Windows, not Ubuntu.

If you really want to remove Windows, but you want to keep your Ubuntu installation and home folder with files, there are several approaches you could take.
You could probably go about this by booting into Ubuntu and opening Gnome Disk Utility or GParted, then removing any Windows partitions from the disk and re-sizing the Ubuntu partition to take up the rest of the disk. Ensure you don't format the entire disk, as this will erase your Ubuntu partition as well, and be careful not to remove any SWAP partitions used by the Ubuntu installation as well.
The other, possibly cleaner, method would be to backup your Home folder and any documents that you'd like to save from Windows and Ubuntu partitions (either on an external drive or using a service like Google drive), then re-installing Ubuntu utilizing the entire disk.

It is a bit of a pain. One way would be to download Boot-Repair-Disc .ISO from -- https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/   ---  Burn it to a USB so it's ready to go. Then delete the Windows partition with the "Disks" app on Ubuntu or "Gparted". Then look for a 512mb partition called FAT32 or EFI. If there isn't one, create it as: 512mb, EFI, as a logical partition, with mount-point at /boot. That will be your GRUB/Boot partition. It should be located at the start of the free space (ie:Left/Top). Then open gnome-terminal and run:
sudo update-initramfs -u  and then: sudo update-grub - Pay attention to any error messages. You can expand the Ubuntu partition to fill in free space/unallocated now. It can take a long time, as in an hour or more depending on partition location. Sometimes it takes less than 5 minutes.... After resizing run sudo update-grub again and reboot. If it fails, reboot with Boot-Repair-Disc on your USB and you can fix the GRUB file in about 5 to 10 minutes..... Painful I know, but this should solve your problem. NOTE: I failed to mention that the EFI/Boot partition must be to the left/top of Ubuntu partition. If Ubuntu is the 1st partition (Left/Top), move it Right/Down to create 512mb of free space to allow for the EFI/Boot partition noted previously. Then expand the Ubuntu partition.
